# Does JQuery have an API for AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm familiar with libraries like YUI and Prototype that I know have an API for AJAX, but I haven't seen anything yet for JQuery. Is there an API out there?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: have you heard of google?  If you search on "AJAX Jquery" it's the first result.

Comment: While I agree about checking the docs -- being an ass when someone doesn't, won't do much to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the cunningly named `jQuery.ajax`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.get()
```

and

```
$.post()
```

is extremely simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the best one http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Ajax [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)